# adhoc reporting in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reporting, adhoc

Im looking for gem/plugin/framework to do good adhoc reporting in ruby/rails.

I dont need charting, just something that will let users pick attributes across multiple tables using and/or clause without knowing sql (or being technical) and will generate a nice table report with pagination and sorting, bonus would be to do pdf export and csv export.

I know I could probably code something pretty good in a week or so, but it would be great if there is already something out there to reuse.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [Ruport](http://www.rubyreports.org/)?

Comment: I browsed the site, couldnt see what I wanted, but maybe didnt dig deep enough, examples were csv and graph, neither are critical or hard for me, the tougher part im looking for is the query building interface. If thats there please let me know some examples to look at.

Comment: Clicking that link directed me to [http://ww4.rubyreports.org/?](http://ww4.rubyreports.org/?) Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: It might have changed since that link was posted in 2011 ;)

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin might give you what you want and some more. It even works with 'cancan'